# How do I get a MessageBox like information window to appear in Java?

Tags: java, messagebox

I'm learning Java and I have no idea how to do this.

I dragged a button on the form in Netbeans, double clicked it and it created this event:

```
@Action
public void HelloClickMethod() 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "The message!", "This is supposed to be the MessageBox title."); 
}
```

This is the exception the IDE brings up.

> Cannot find symbol. Symbol: showMessageDialog()

**Edit 1>**
Now I changed it to this:

```
@Action
public void HelloClickMethod()
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "The message!", "This is supposed to be the MessageBox title.",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

However the IDE is saying I have an error in the word 'this'. "Cannot find symbol". I don't understand. Why is it so dificult and why are the errors so esoteric. :P

Comment: Compiler messages *always* look esoteric if you are new to a language.  The problem is that no compiler can know what you thought you were trying to write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of the following cause: you might not be "importing" the package containing JOptionPane. Try:

```
 import javax.swing.*;
```

On top of your source file. Or, use

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "The message!", "This is supposed to be the MessageBox title.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

After questioner edit:

Other cause is the location of the method, if you are in an static context, you can't use `this`.

Comment: Looking back at the retardedness of my question is very humbling. Tip! Never look at code/questions you've written in the past, you'll only blush. Hahahaha.

Answer (score 0):

The showMessageDialog method does not take 3 parameters. Try this:

```
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "The message!", "This is supposed to be the MessageBox title.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

There are 3 methods named showMessageDialog, one with 2 parameters (component and message), 4 parameters (component, message, title, message type) and 5 parameters (component, message, title, message type, icon).

Comment: I don't have javac in this computer but I am almost certain that it can take 3 arguments.http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: I am looking at the API docs http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html and there are only 3 methods? I see the tutorial that shows code with 3 parameters but...I have to check.

Comment: OK. I checked. I have javase6 installed and it does not allow the 3 parameter version given in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ErrorMSG", "Title!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE)
```